# execute anonymous pl/sql block file with values from java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I have an anonymous pl/sql block in an sql file and I want to execute and assign values to it in Java. My sql block looks like this

```
    DECLARE

            someInput1 NUMBER(1);

            someInput2 NUMBER(2);

            someString1 VARCHAR(100);

    BEGIN

            someInput1 := ‘&1’;

            someInput2 := ‘&2’;

            --get name in table A

            BEGIN

                    SELECT a.value INTO someString1

                    FROM TABLE_A a

                    WHERE a.id = someInput1;               

            END;



            UPDATE TABLE_B b

            SET b.someStringRow = someString1

            WHERE b.someIntRow = someInput2;

            COMMIT;

    END;

    /

    exit;
```

What I am planning to do is load the sql file in a Java String, change ‘&1’ to ?1 and execute it as a CallableStatement. However, I am getting

```
    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “” when expecting one of the following
    begin function package pragma procedure subtype us <an identifier> <a double quoted delimited identifier> form current cursor
```

Error occured at lines in DECLARE section

Is my approach an acceptable solution, if yes, what may be wrong in my approach?

Are there other better solution for my problem? Thanks

Comment: Remove quotes around `&1` and `&2`. Define the missing `someString1`

Comment: You don't need the local variables really, you can just refer to the bind variables directly. Did you really mean `?1` though, not just `?` for both substitution variables? It won't like the trailing `/` or the `exit;`, though it ought to say that - does you real code have the curly quote marks or have those been introduced as you created the question? But why is this a PL/SQL block at all, or two DML statements?

Comment: i will replace & with ? so that i can set value using callableStatement.setInt(1, javaInt) ... and so on. the pl block had more statements i just cant type it as i am using a phone. also, when i remove the quotes on &1 i get invalid column index exception as what ravinder suggested

Comment: @FrankSmith - you don't need to number the `?` placeholders though; the first one in the command will be set with `setInt(1, ...)`, as they are positional not named. It looks like you are already removing the quotes around the substitution variables. The rest of the error you left out might be helpful, but I suspect it is the `/` and `exit;` that it isn't happy with.

Comment: I tried changing all the &number to ? and remove / and exit; i forgot to mention that i am still using jdk 1.5 though i dont know it it has an impact

Comment: I did not look into that you tagged this as `java`. How are you defining and calling this code block in `java`?

Comment: i am reading the file using BufferedReader and store it as a string. i then use CallableStatement, set values and execute it as callableStatement.execute(). The stored proc is working well when i execute it in sql developer

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove quote marks, and replace `&1` with `:1`, and you should be fine, also, you will need remove `'/'` and `exit;` and they relate to `sqlplus` and not to `pl/sql` directly